# sonarqube error java insufficient memory

Tags: amazon-ec2, sonarqube

I am trying to setup  sonarqube on ec2 instance Amazon Linux AMI. on t2 micro instance. using the below sonarqube version:6.0,  java:java-1.8.0-openjdk, mysql:mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.39, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

after sonar start command:

```
    sudo ./sonar.sh start
```

sonar is not starting. after checking in logs gives out below message.

```
          --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
   Launching a JVM...
    Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

       2018.05.16 19:30:50 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or 
     creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
      2018.05.16 19:30:50 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch 
     process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171- 
      7.b10.37.amzn1.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G - 
   Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC - 
   XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 - 
      XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError - 
   Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0- 
      openjdk-1.8.0.171-7.b10.37.amzn1.x86_64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar - 
   cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer 
      /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process620905092992598791properties
       OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: 
    os::commit_memory(0x00000000c5330000, 181207040, 0) failed; 
  error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 181207040 bytes for 
committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/sonarqube/hs_err_pid30955.log
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Below Memory info:

```
  /proc/meminfo:
  MemTotal:        1011176 kB
  MemFree:           78024 kB
  MemAvailable:      55140 kB
  Buffers:            8064 kB
  Cached:            72360 kB
  SwapCached:            0 kB
  Active:           860160 kB
  Inactive:          25868 kB
  Active(anon):     805628 kB
  Inactive(anon):       48 kB
  Active(file):      54532 kB
  Inactive(file):    25820 kB
  Unevictable:           0 kB
  Mlocked:               0 kB
  SwapTotal:             0 kB
  SwapFree:              0 kB
  Dirty:               108 kB
  Writeback:             0 kB
  AnonPages:        805628 kB
  Mapped:            30700 kB
  Shmem:                56 kB
  Slab:              28412 kB
  SReclaimable:      16632 kB
  SUnreclaim:        11780 kB
  KernelStack:        3328 kB
  PageTables:         6108 kB
  NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
  Bounce:                0 kB
  WritebackTmp:          0 kB
  CommitLimit:      505588 kB
  Committed_AS:    1348288 kB
  VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
  VmallocUsed:           0 kB
  VmallocChunk:          0 kB
  AnonHugePages:         0 kB
  ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
  ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
  HugePages_Total:       0
  HugePages_Free:        0
  HugePages_Rsvd:        0
  HugePages_Surp:        0
  Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
  DirectMap4k:       47104 kB
  DirectMap2M:     1001472 kB


     CPU:total 1 (initial active 1) (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) 
   family 6 model 63 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, 
  ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, tsc, 
  bmi1, bmi2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to increase the maximum allowed heap size memory for your SonarQube application ?

You can do so by editing the `sonar.properties` file, found in your SQ installation folder.

You can [follow this guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Java+Process+Memory) in order to configure your SQ max heap size.